# How do I save some files under a directory in a new directory after making some changes

Tags: c#

I opened a directory and I read some files in that directory amd made some changes, now I want to save the changes with the same file names at F:\BI\Out\ and keep the original files.
when I added these two lines
                        var outFilePath = @"F:\BI\Out\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
                        File.WriteAllText(outFilePath, text);
I was able to save the files under the new folder\Out,
but when I opened them I found that only one file is changed correctly and all the other files the old words are replace by blank space not by the new words.
Can anyone help me Thanks

```
    string text = "";
    string[] files;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\BI\In\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtEtlPath.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter path");
            txtEtlPath.Focus();
        }

        else
        {

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                {
                    text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    text = text.Replace("Company_Address", txtCompanyAddress.Text + "_BI");
                    text = text.Replace("Company_Name", txtCompanyName.Text.Trim() + "_BIDW");
                    text = text.Replace("C:\\BIfolder",cboDrive.Text + txtEtlPath.Text.Trim());
                     var outFilePath = @"F:\BI\Out\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
                     File.WriteAllText(outFilePath, text);
                }
```

Comment: Search is your friend, be it on google or Stackoverflow.[**`Directory.CreateDirectory`** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**`How to: Write to a Text File`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Within your foreach () loop:

If you want the subfolder structure of the files found, do a replace on the filepath:

```
var outFilePath = file.Replace(@"F:\BI\In\", @"F:\BI\Out\");
```

You will need to create the subfolder before you can write the changed file:

```
new FileInfo(outFilePath)).Directory.Create();
```

If you don't want the subfolders, you can write directly into the top folder:

```
var outFilePath = @"F:\BI\Out\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
```

Writing is simple, just keep in mind there is an optional encoding parameter:

```
File.WriteAllText(outFilePath, text);
```

Comment: I was able to save the files under the new folder\Out, but when I opened them I found that only one file is changed correctly and all the other files the old words are replace by blank space not by the new words

Comment: I can't see anything posted that would cause that, put breakpoints on each of text.Replace lines, hover over the text and textbox variables to see what has been read and what each Replace is changing.

Comment: Yes I tried it and it takes the same values I entered but when I write the alltext it is replace with blank, this is weird.            Anyhow thanks alot for help